# How To Show The Application Running In The Background And How We Can Stop Their Operation?

Tags: java, android, optimization, battery-saver

I want to make a battery saver application on which i want to show all the applications running in the background into recyclerview and after showing them then i want to kill all the applications that are running in the background. Is there any solution available? I am developing an app on android studio using java language and my version is 3.2.1. I tried so many codes that are available here but they are not working at all.